# Why is VueJs generating a comment instead of a template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I'm trying to use:  https://github.com/MisRob/vue-tree-navigation 
I'm not using nodejs and trying to use this on a static website using complied javascript files in the dist folder, but it just generates a comment like this:
`<!--function(e,n,r,i){return Pt(t,e,n,r,i,!0)}-->`

Same issue as this guy in another library:  https://github.com/lkmadushan/vue-tuicalendar/issues/7

My code is below:

```
Vue.component('vue-tree-navigation', VueTreeNavigation);




<div id="app>
<b-card-text>
   <vue-tree-navigation />
</b-card-text>
</div>

Vue.component('vue-tree-navigation', VueTreeNavigation);
var App = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
......
```

When it runs it replaces  tag and contents with `< !--function(e,n,r,i){return Pt(t,e,n,r,i,!0)}-->` and no component is rendered

Comment: It looks like you are missing a quote `<div id="app">`

Comment: Also, you can use self-closing tags freely in vue templates, but not in standard HTML file (i am talking about `<vue-tree-navigation />`, it should be `<vue-tree-navigation></vue-tree-navigation>`)